# strange question about PHP convert string to int

Tags: php, string, integer

im trying to convert string to integer but return 0 or wrong number.
Below is the code i have tested.
Anyone know why?
Thanks

```
<?php
echo gettype(0x55)."\n"; //type is integer
echo 0x55."\n"; //this is correct
echo (int)"0x55"."\n"; //why 0?
echo intval("0x55"); //why 0?
```

return

> integer
> 85
> 0
> 0

Comment: because the string has a `0` before it has any Non-Numeric (the `x`) which terminates the cast, or `intval()` as its not a numeric

Comment: If you can post an actual code sample with the literal string you're trying to convert we can probably give you a more useful answer than "well I guess don't do that".

Comment: If you want the decimal value of a hexadecimal string, use `hexdec`. But remove the "0x" first.

Comment: Simple test, run `echo (int)"3x55"."\n";` and you will get `3`

Comment: Also see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting and https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.numeric-strings.php

Comment: specify base as 0 resolved my problem. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `intval()` parses base 10, so it ignores the `0x` prefix.

If you specify the base as `0`, it will determine the base dynamically from the string prefix: `0x` means hex, `0` means octal.

So use `intval("0x55", 0)`.

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/B0kCTE)

I don't think there's any equivalent for the typecast syntax `(int)`.